# Why does Android use JUnit over TestNG even if Cedric Beust created TestNg and was part of Android team?

Tags: android, junit, testng

Just curious about it...

[Cedric Beust](http://beust.com/weblog/) created [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) and I understand from an interview I read was part of the Android team. 
Why did they chose to use JUnit as the testing infrastructure for Android Eclipse Tools?

Isn't TestNG supposed to a better than JUnit?

Comment: There are few developers that belongs to the Android team here in StackOverflow... so it's hard that they answer this question. You mostly will get personal opinions of SO users, instead of the answer you want... if I were you I would just ask Android team directly, via its Google Group or email.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I actually picked JUnit over TestNG for Android testing, I thought it was more lightweight than TestNG for on-device testing. That was in 2007, I'm not sure I would make that same choice today.

Comment: +1 There you have, the power of twitter and StackOveflow together :) :) Thank you Cedric!

Comment: Thanks Cedric, are you aware that are now projects like androidjunit4(at github) that allow junit4 tests on emulator/devices? someone might just code up some adaptor to make testNG happen.

Answer (score -1):

This might be impossible to answer ( at least with code )

Probably by the time TestNG was created there were a number of JUnit test aready.... who knows...

Let's ask it to Cedric directly :) :)